# Why $\sum^C_{c\neq c^*}P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)]+p^*(1-p^*) \leq (C-1)\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}[1-\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}]+p^*(1-p^*)?$

Tags: bayesian, k-nearest-neighbour

I have the following theorem in my textbook:

As the number of samples goes to infinity the error rate of 1-NN is no more than twice the Bayes error rate.

Proof sketch:

Abbreviate notation $P(c|x) := P(Y=c|x)$

The expected (Bayes) error of the Bayes classifier (at x) is $$1-\text{ max }_{c\in\{1,...,C\}}P(c|x)$$

and the expected rate of $1-NN$ (at x) is

$$\sum^C_{c=1}P(c|x_{nn})[1-P(c|x)]$$

observe that as the number of samples goes to infinity, $m\to \infty$,

$$P(c|x)\approx P(c|x_{nn})$$

thus the expected rate of 1-NN (at x) is $$\sum^C_{c=1}P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)]$$

We need to show $$\sum^C_{c=1}P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)]\leq 2[1-\text{ max }_{c\in\{1,...,C\}}P(c|x)]$$:

Let $c^*=\text{ argmax }_{c\in\{1,...,C\}}P(c|x)$ and $p^*=P(c^*|x)$. Observe that $$\sum^C_{c=1}P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)]=\sum^C_{c\neq c^*}P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)]+p^*(1-p^*)\\ \leq (C-1)\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}[1-\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}]+p^*(1-p^*)\\ = (1-p^*)[1-\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}+p^*]$$

Where the second line follows since the sum is maximised when all "$P(c|x)$" have the same value. And since $p^*<1$ we are done.

> I don't completely understand how the second line follows. Could someone show me please?

Comment: Are you sure your expression for $c^* = \arg \max \dots$ is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define  $y_c:=P(c|x)$, $\forall{c} \in \{1,2,\ldots, C\}$, then we have $y_{c^{*}}=p^{*}$

Also, let $f\left(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{c^{*}-1},y_{c^{*}+1},\ldots,y_C\right)=\sum\limits_{c\neq c^{*}}y_c(1-y_c)$, this is the function we want to maximize (note the absence of $c^{*}$ in the variables).

Also, we have a constraint that $\sum\limits_{c=1}^{C}y_c=1$, since the posterior probabilities must sum to $1$.

Let's define the constraint function $g\left(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{c^{*}-1},y_{c^{*}+1},\ldots,y_C\right)=\sum\limits_{c\neq c^{*}}y_c + p^{*}-1=0$,

s.t. we have to maximize $f$ w.r.t. the constraint $g$.

It means we must have $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ for some $\lambda$, when $f$ is an extremum (using the Lagrange multiplier).

$\implies \begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           1-2y_1 \\
           1-2y_2 \\
           \vdots \\
           1-2y_{c^{*}-1} \\
           1-2y_{c^{*}+1} \\
           \vdots \\
           1-2y_{C} 
         \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align}$ $=\lambda 
    \begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           \vdots \\
           1 \\
           1 \\
           \vdots \\
           1 
         \end{bmatrix}
        \end{align}$
$\implies y_c = \dfrac{\lambda-1}{2}$, $\forall{c} \neq c^{*}$

Also, we must have the constraint satisfied, i.e.,

$\sum\limits_{c\neq c^{*}}y_c + p^{*}-1=\sum\limits_{c\neq c^{*}}\dfrac{\lambda-1}{2}+p^{*}-1= 0$

$\implies (C-1)\dfrac{\lambda-1}{2}+p^{*}-1= 0$

$\implies y_c=\dfrac{\lambda-1}{2}=\dfrac{1-p^{*}}{C-1}$, $\forall{c} \neq c^{*}$

Hence, at **maximum**, we have,

$f_{max}\left(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{c^{*}-1},y_{c^{*}+1},\ldots,y_C\right)=\sum\limits_{c\neq c^{*}}y_c(1-y_c)=\sum\limits_{c\neq c^{*}}\dfrac{1-p^{*}}{C-1}\left(1-\dfrac{1-p^{*}}{C-1}\right)$

$=(C-1).\dfrac{1-p^{*}}{C-1}\left(1-\dfrac{1-p^{*}}{C-1}\right)$

Now, since we have $f \leq f_{max}$,

$\implies \sum\limits^C_{c\neq c^*}P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)] \leq (C-1)\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}[1-\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}]$

$\implies \sum\limits^C_{c\neq c^*}P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)]+p^*(1-p^*) \leq (C-1)\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}[1-\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}]+p^*(1-p^*)$

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, quick answer since I'm on my way out the door: you need to think about maximizing the curve

$$
\sum_{c\neq c^*} x_c(1-x_c)\,,\hspace{3em} \text{with } x_c\geq0\,,\hspace{3em}\text{and}\,\, \sum_{c\neq c*} = 1-x_{c^*}\,.
$$

A bit of straightforward calculus (or noticing that $x(1-x)<x$ in the domain) will show you that this is maximized when $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_{C}$, here when $x_c = (1-x_{c^*})/(C-1)$. So

$$
\sum_{c-c^*} P(c|x)[1-P(c|x)] \leq \sum_{c-c^*} P(c^*|x)[1-P(c^*|x)] = (C-1)P(c^*|x)[1-P(c^*|x)] = (C-1)\left(\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}\right)\left[1-\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}\right]\,.
$$

The result follows.

Comment: How exactly did you know that it's maximized when $x_1=x_2=...=x_C$? Also, why exactly is $P(c^*|x)=\frac{1-p^*}{C-1}$? Isn't $P(c^*|x)=p^*$? Also, don't understand why $x_c=1(1-x_{c^*})/(C-1)$. Could you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: 1. The straight forward calculus is Lagrange Multiplies: to maximize $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=c$, find the joint solution to $\nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x)$ and $g(x) = c$. This is pretty straight forward in this case if you know calculus, but if you don't writing out the computation isn't going to be fairly useful. I would give it a try yourself and ask if you have questions.

2. $P(c^*|x) \neq (1-p*)/(C-1)$, instead we're trying to find the *maximum* that the left hand side of my expression could possibly be to bound it. By (1), that maximum occurs when the probabilities are equal.

Comment: 3. If all $x_c$ are equal for $c\neq c^*$ then $1-p^* = \sum_{c\neq c^*} x_c = (1-C)x_c$, so $x_c =  (1-p^*)/(1-C)$.